# Jquery Jcarousel use multiple instances

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Ok so I have two instances on a page where I am using Jquery Jcarousel but here is the snag...

One of the instances is a "slideshow" or "image gallery" so I need the carousel to cycle one by one however...

In the footer I have another instance where a list of "facts" are cycling at a cycle rate of 3 at a time.

How can I get around this so I can basically have my cake and eat it too?

I want to be able to have the slideshow cycle one by one AND have the "facts" list to cycle 3 items at a time.

I have tried copying and renaming the function to something else like "facts" but this did not work.

This is the plugin I am using: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Help!

Comment: Please refere this  http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_multiple.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is there in their [documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_multiple.html):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Initialise the first and second carousel by class selector.
    // Note that they use both the same configuration options (none in this case).
    jQuery('.first-and-second-carousel').jcarousel();

    // If you want to use a caoursel with different configuration options,
    // you have to initialise it seperately.
    // We do it by an id selector here.
    jQuery('#third-carousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this however... I want the cycle to be different - in their documentation I can't see how to change this?

Comment: Can you say like what it should be different?

Comment: The cycle - so if you go here: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_multiple.html 
click on the arrow you will see 3 items cycle... this is good for one instance however... I want the same functionality but with a 1 by 1 cycle.

Comment: Now my question. Did you really read the [API Documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Defining-The-Number-Of-Visible-Items)? Pass the `visible` parameter: *If passed, the width/height of the items will be calculated and set depending on the width/height of the clipping, so that exactly that number of items will be visible.* By default it is `3`. You can set it as `1`.